# Prove that the vectors of the set is a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

Let $1\leq n\in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\mathcal{E}:=(e_1, \ldots , e_n)$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We define $\displaystyle{e_i':=\sum_{j=1}^ie_j}$.

I want to show also that $(e_1', \ldots , e_n')$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For that we use induction.

Base case: Do we start from $n=3$ that we have above or from $n=1$ ?

Inductive Hypothesis: We assume that it holds for $n=k$.

Inductive Step: We want to show that it holds for $n=k+1$. Could you give me a hint how we can show that if we have an additional element and a higher dimension we get again a basis?

Comment: Why not start from $n=1$ for the base case?  (I don't see $3$ above)

Comment: We cannot represent the vector $e_{k+1}$ with any linear combination of $e'_1, \cdots, e'_k$ but we can with $e'_1, \cdots, e'_k, e'_{k+1}$  Therefore $e'_{k+1}$ is independent from $(e'_1, \cdots, e'_k)$.  This shows that the vectors are independent.  And if we have $n$ of them, span the space.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ah sorry, I forgot to add the part of the previous subquestion. It was: Let $n=3$. Calculate $e_1', e_2', e_3'$ and show that $(e_1', e_2', e_3')$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. $$$$ But we start at the induction with $n=1$, or not?

Comment: We can't represent the vector $e_{k+1}$ with any linear combination of $e_1', \ldots , e_k'$ because $e_{k+1}$ has a $1$ at the position $k+1$ but all the other vectors have there $0$, correct? So we use the inductive hypothesis to assume that the set $(e_1', \ldots , e_k')$ is linearly independent and since $e_{k+1}'$ is linearly independent from that set we get that the set $(e_1', \ldots , e_k', e_{k+1}')$ is linearly independent? @DougM

Answer (score 1):

It suffice to prove $\mathrm{rank}\{e_1', \cdots , e_n'\}=n$.

Consider the linear transformation bewteen these two sets of vectors:$$(e_1', \cdots , e_n')=(e_1, \cdots , e_n)\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\ 
0 &  0& 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}=(e_1, \cdots , e_n)A.$$
Note that $\det A=1 \neq 0$. Therefore $\mathrm{rank}\{e_1', \cdots , e_n'\}=\mathrm{rank}\{e_1, \cdots , e_n\}=n$.

Comment: In that way we don't use induction, do we? This is an other way, or not?

Comment: Yes, it is. I think this is the most direct way to do it. You can also use induction. What you reply to Doug M is actually okay.